# C# creating XML output file without <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Tags: c#, xml, output

I'm new to C# development so maybe a very simple question here.

I'm trying to get an output which starts as this:

```
    <ns0:NamespaceEnvelope xmlns:ns0="http://url.to.NamespaceEnvelope/v1.0">
```

But am getting this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ns0>
```

This is my source:

```
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = "  ";
        settings.NewLineChars = "\r\n";
        settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("employees.xml", settings))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("ns0"); 
            writer.WriteStartElement("Firstsection");
```

How can I get rid of:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

And how can I change:

```
     writer.WriteStartElement("ns0");
```

To be able to output it as:

```
    <ns0:NamespaceEnvelope xmlns:ns0="http://url.to.NamespaceEnvelope/v1.0">
```

As this:

```
    writer.WriteStartElement("ns0:NamespaceEnvelope xmlns:ns0="http://url.to.NamespaceEnvelope/v1.0"");
```

Is asking for an ")" probably because of the "surrounding the http part.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to escape your quotes in that last line. For each literal `"` just put a `\"`. Look up escaping if you haven't come across this before. That having been said I am sure there are better ways to declare namespaced elements than that anyway.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfche0ka(v=vs.110).aspx for some stuff on writing out namespaces properly.

Comment: Hi Chris,

Thank you for your input, tried the escape \ which solves the error message but than gives:

Invalid name character in 'ns0:NamespaceEnvelope xmlns:ns0="http://url.to.NamespaceEnvelope/v1.0"'. The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

Than changed it to:
writer.WriteStartElement("ns0");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "ns0", null, "http://url.to.NamespaceEnvelope/v1.0");

Which gives me
<ns0 xmlns:ns0="http://url.to.NamespaceEnvelope/v1.0">

So now I need to get the last step to get
<ns0 
into
<ns0:NamespaceEnvelope

Thanks

Comment: Lol, the answer was just a bit lower on the external page:

`writer.WriteStartElement("ns0", "NamespaceEnvelope", "http://url.to.NamespaceEnvelope/v1.0");`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
```

Answer (score 12):

```
 private string RemoveXmlDefinition(string xml)
 {
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    xdoc.Declaration = null;

    return xdoc.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: there's always an alternative;