# How to Remove <xml version="1.0"> Element in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

my xml content in variable look like:

```
 var xml = DownloadString(@"http://192.168.1.50:8983/solr/core-live/select?q=*%3A*&wt=xslt&tr=custom.xsl");
```

DownloadString is a function/method

```
public static string DownloadString(string address) 
     {
        string text;
         using (var client = new WebClient()) 
         {
           text = client.DownloadString(address);
         }
           return text;
      }
```

and when i am debugging on xml variable and xml o/p look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml version="1.0">
<item>
<sku>12944</sku>
<title>test</title</item>
</xml>
```

i want to remove second node(`<xml version="1.0">`) and last node(`</xml>`) from same variable.

then after save content in xml file using this:

```
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText("test.xml", xml);
```

regards,
Jatin

Comment: But then it won't be XML? You want to remove the XML tags?

Comment: @DrSchizo no not remove first tag i want to remove second <xml version="1.0"> tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I using both string replace() function on DownloadString() mathod.

I was try this code and its working fine.

```
public static string DownloadString(string address) 
        {
                    string text;
                    using (var client = new WebClient()) 
                    {
                        text = client.DownloadString(address);
                    }
                    return text.Replace("<xml version=\"1.0\">", "").Replace("</xml>", "");
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
xdoc.Declaration = null;
return xdoc;
```

[C# creating XML output file without <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333973/c-sharp-creating-xml-output-file-without-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use replace method in string

```
                text = text.Replace("<xml version=\"1.0\">", "");
                text = text.Replace("</xml>", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case in addition to @user1040975's solution to the problem I also had to set the XmlWriterSettings's OmitXmlDeclaration attribute as true, so the new declaration without the Encoding I created would appear, at the end the code looked like this:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
{
    Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false),
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true
};
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(convertedPath, settings))
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(innerXml);
    xDoc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0",null,null);
    xDoc.Save(xmlWriter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string filePath = "C:\\file.xml";
                List<string> strList = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                int ctr = 0;
                foreach (string str in strList)
                {
                    ctr++;
                    if (ctr == 1 || ctr == strList.Count)
                        continue;
                    sb.Append(str);
                }
```